# Getting an image from a _POST value

Tags: php, jquery, html

so I'm setting up a little system where on one page, you put in a couple images using the input tag and then when you hit submit it takes you to a new page to review your entries.

Right now I've got this value being passed to the second page:

```
$main_image         =$_POST['main_image'];
```

The input for the picture comes from the first page as this:

```
<tr>
    <th align="right">Main Photo</th>
    <td><input type="file" name="main_image" size="30"></td>
</tr>
```

However when I put an image down at the bottom of the page like this:

```
<tr>
    <th align="right">Main Rendering/Photo</th>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $main_image; ?>" width="50px"></td>
</tr>
```

the photo appears as the little empty box with the missing image icon.

Am I getting the image wrong, implementing it wrong, or what?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `<input type='file' />` to upload the images? If so, they'll be in PHP's `$_FILES` array, not the `$_POST` array. Also, after receiving the images on upload, you'd want to put them somewhere, and echo out the path where you moved them to (see PHP's `move_uploaded_file()` function)

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: can u provide us the input u are using ?

Comment: @MounerMostafa I added it

Answer (score 1):

You can only echo image files with encode them or with changing Content-Type header. You can do it like :

```
$imageFile = $_FILES['yourInputTypeFileName']['tmp_name'];
$imageFileContents = file_get_contents($imageFile);
$withBase64 = base64_encode($imageFileContents);
$imageType = substr($imageFile ,strrpos($imageFile, '.')+1, strlen($imageFile));
echo '<img src="data:image/'.$imageType.';base64,'.$withBase64.'"/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be possible in the way you're trying to do it. When a file gets placed into the `$_POST` variable, it's given a temporary name for a file that only lives a very short amount of time (probably only reliably until the end of the initial page request, and then PHP will clean it up). This won't work for an `<img>` tag because when the browser loads on the next page, the browser is going to perform a separate request for that file after the initial page load, and it won't be there anymore.

The correct way to do this is to use `move_uploaded_file()` to permanently save the file to disk using the `tmp_name` variable provided in `$_POST`. This means you'll have to come up with a way of tracking it and potentially cleaning it up if the user decides not to use it.

I wish your approach could work. It would be very convenient :)

Comment: Files don't get placed inside `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

try this one but make sure first that your form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"` like this one

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

then use this code

```
<?php 
$size = getimagesize($_FILES['main_image']['tmp_name']); //get size
$image = "data:" . $size["mime"] . ";base64," . base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['main_image']['tmp_name'])); //get image
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" />'; //outpout
?>
```